# What is the default DDS implementation used in the Foxy release?

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FastRTPS has been the default DDS implementation for ROS2 in Eloquent and Dashing. However, I heard this might change in ROS2 Foxy. What will the default DDS implementation used in ROS2 Foxy be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353295/what-is-the-default-dds-implementation-used-in-the-foxy-release?/) by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2020-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its still FastRTPS.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0